# How to truncate and load part of data in a table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using a snowflake table which doesn't have a partition mechanism instead it has micro partitions.
We have a ew requirement to perform a different type of full load on the table.

Scenario:
I have a table with three columns: ID, Name, Current_Location
Records on Day1:

```
Se  Name    Current_Location     Rate
1   A           L1               100
2   B           L2               200
3   C           L3               300
4   D           L4               400
5   E           L5               500
6   F           L6               600
7   G           L7               700
8   H           L7               800
```

My requirement is that I get new data everyday for each `Current_Location` with different rates i.e.
Day2:

```
Se  Name    Current_Location     Rate
6   P           L6               6000
7   G           L7               7000
8   H           L7               1100
9   Z           L7               1200
```

Based on the value in the column: `Current_Location`, I have truncate the previous records first and then load the new records. For example, with Current_Location `L7` In the above scenario, there are two records for L7 on Day1 but on Day2, I get three records.
So I have to truncate

```
7   G           L7               700
8   H           L7               800
```

and then load all three new records from Day2 into my table. The same goes for L6. The final table after truncate and load should look like:

```
Se  Name    Current_Location     Rate
1   A           L1               100
2   B           L2               200
3   C           L3               300
4   D           L4               400
5   E           L5               500
6   P           L6               6000
7   G           L7               7000
8   H           L7               1100
9   Z           L7               1200
```

To achieve this, I thought of implementing:

1. Insert all of the new data into the target_table. At this moment, the target_table contains new & old records as well.
2. Then create a view on top of it by selecting max(Current_Location) and exposing it to the user.

`create or replace view final_view as select * from target_table where Current_Location = (select max(Current_Location) from target_table)`

But I have to truncate old records with old Current_Location later and once I remove them, my table and view becomes the same.
I am using Snowflake database and there is no concept of partitioning in it albeit there are micro partitions.
Is there any efficient way to do the same operation ?

Edit1: I explored Merge query :

```
MERGE INTO t1 USING t2 ON t1.t1Key = t2.t2Key
    WHEN MATCHED AND t2.marked = 1 THEN DELETE
    WHEN MATCHED AND t2.isNewStatus = 1 THEN UPDATE SET val = t2.newVal, status = t2.newStatus
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET val = t2.newVal
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (val, status) VALUES (t2.newVal, t2.newStatus);
```

Once a case is executed, will the next case is also checked ?
For example: A row matches the DELETE condition, it gets deleted. Now I have to insert the row with the same key into the table. Will the case for `WHEN NOT MACTHED` be also executed ? Or once a case is executed, the control exits the MERGE Query ?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information here. Also, this looks like a duplicate question that you've already asked?  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044360/can-we-use-exist-in-a-sql-query-to-search-delete-the-records-from-a-table

Comment: Yes, I had some more information for this question since I got a way to do it (I also posted the way I did it in that question). I was editing it but by mistake saved it before I adding my changes from notepad to the browser. Raised a flag for moderator intervention just a while ago. So I posted the question there.

Answer (score 2):

I see that `MERGE` statement will cause trouble as the rows in the target table will be joined against multiple rows in the source, i.e is non-deterministic as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html#nondeterministic-results-for-update-and-delete)

What about you first `delete` the records using unique values of `Current_Location` from the new data set, then `insert` all the new records received?

```
DELETE FROM T1
   WHERE Current_Location in (SELECT DISTINCT Current_Location FROM T2);

INSERT INTO T1
   SELECT * FROM T2;
```

That seems to produce the final table you require, correct me if I missed something.

To keep track of such operations you may introduce two history tables T3, T4 where T3 holds the daily deleted records along with deletion date/timestamp and T4 holds the newly received records with insertion date/timestamp

so first, execute something like

```
INSERT INTO T3 
Select *, CURRENT_DATE   // Or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP safer if multiple runs received on same day
     FROM T1
       WHERE Current_Location in (SELECT DISTINCT Current_Location FROM T2);

INSERT INTO T4 
Select *, CURRENT_DATE   // Or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP safer if multiple runs received on same day
     FROM T2;
```

Then execute the delete and insert statements suggested, and in that case, you may consider cleaning the history table periodically by creating a scheduled [task](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html) that will delete older than certain days as a threshold, i.e. 90 days or more whatever suits your business needs, just to avoid accumulating so much of history records.

**Note:** you may consider [streams](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html) instead of the history tables suggested for proper CDC but I opted for a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working with STREAMS?

Streams are similar to Change Data Capture. A stream on a certain table shows you exactly which rows have been added/removed/updated regarding the table. As a consequence you may be able to make your logic above way easier.

More information and the structure of such a stream for selecting the changes can be found here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html

On top of that you can also try to use TASKS. A task is a job that runs a certain statement (e.g. your truncate) and is executed under a certain condition (e.g. your case above). For more information see here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html

And one last edit for another hint: Maybe MERGE fits your needs too as it combines INSERT and UPDATE/DELETE. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

Comment: `A stream on a certain table shows you exactly which rows have been added/removed/updated regarding the table` 
My data is coming from a different file and it first goes to a Staging table. Only after that, I have write a logic to truncate older data and insert new data.
Can I use Streams in this scenario ?

Comment: I explored the merge option and added my doubts in the question since it is too big to comment here. Can you pelase check that ?

Comment: You can try to create a stream on your staging table (CREATE STREAM x ON TABLE y), add some data to the table and then query your stream (SELECT * FROM x). Maybe the results are some good input for further processing? (maybe I got it wrong but when your source_table is the same as your target_table, then you may use something like a temporary table which you delete after processing)

Comment: Regarding your MERGE-questions: Why do you delete and then insert with the same key? Why not update then?

Regarding the conditions: It depends on the conditions in there and whether you are using UPDATE, DELETE and/or INSERT. You can find more information in the section about non-determenistic and deterministic queries (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html#duplicate-join-behavior) but when the condition matches, its executed (as far as I know)

Comment: I cannot run update because of the following case:
If I have 3 rows on day1 for L7 and on day2 I get only one row for L7, the final table should contain only one row which we got from day2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221998/discussion-between-metadata-and-marcel).