# Can we use exist in a SQL query to search & delete the records from a table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using a snowflake table which doesn't have a partition mechanism instead it has micro partitions. We have a new requirement to perform a different type of full load on the table.

Scenario: I have a table with three columns: ID, Name, Current_Location Records on Day1:

```
Se  Name    Current_Location     Rate
1   A           L1               100
2   B           L2               200
3   C           L3               300
4   D           L4               400
5   E           L5               500
6   F           L6               600
7   G           L7               700
8   H           L7               800
```

My requirement is that I get new data everyday for each Current_Location with different rates i.e. Day2:

```
Se  Name    Current_Location     Rate
6   P           L6               6000
7   G           L7               7000
8   H           L7               1100
9   Z           L7               1200
```

Based on the value in the column: Current_Location, I have to delete the previous records first and then load the new records. For example, with Current_Location L7 In the above scenario, there are two records for L7 on Day1 but on Day2, I get three records. So I have to delete

```
7   G           L7               700
8   H           L7               800
```

and then load all three new records from Day2 into my table. The same goes for L6. The final table after delete and load should look like:

```
Se  Name    Current_Location     Rate
1   A           L1               100
2   B           L2               200
3   C           L3               300
4   D           L4               400
5   E           L5               500
6   P           L6               6000
7   G           L7               7000
8   H           L7               1100
9   Z           L7               1200
```

To achieve this I implemented:

```
select * 
from maintable 
where exists (select 1 
              from stagingtable 
              where maintable.keycolumn = stagingtable.keycolumn)
```

That query is resulting in the data I want.

```
delete from maintable 
where exists select 1 
             from stagingtable 
             where maintable.keycolumn = stagingtable.keycolumn
```

I converted it to a `delete` query so that I can delete the records using that query and then run

```
insert into maintable (select * from stagingtable)
```

Is there a better approach than using

```
delete from maintable 
where exists select 1 
             from stagingtable 
             where maintable.keycolumn = stagingtable.keycolumn
```

Could anyone let me know how can I tune/tweak the query if it can improve the performance of the query ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You terminology is confused TRUNCATE purges the entire table DELETE deletes rows

Comment: @P.Salmon That was a mistake. I should've used DELETE in the first place instead of TRUNCATE. I changed it now.

Comment: You could use a `merge` statement to roll up two statements into one. Although this wouldn't necessarily speed up your query, it does make it simpler. Merge query documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

Comment: If merge statement doesn't speed up the query, is there any other way I can implement it ?

Comment: You could enable automatic clustering on the table with the `Current_Location` field as the cluster key. This should speed up the delete but there is a cost implication of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `merge`

```
merge into maintable using (
    select keycolumn, v 
    from stagingtable 
) as b on maintable.keycolumn = b.keycolumn
  when matched then update set maintable.v = b.v
  when not matched then insert (keycolumn, v) values (b.keycolumn, b.v);
```

Comment: Here is a scenario, if I have 3 records on day1 and on day2 I got only 1 record, I have to remove 3 records of day1 and just insert that one new record from day2. So the final data in the table will be only one record from day2. I haven't used the merge query until now. Can you please let me know if the above merge query works for my requirement ?